# Execute Dynamic DDL statement in teradata stored procedure?

Tags: stored-procedures, teradata

How to Execute Dynamic DDL statements IN TERADATA?

```
CREATE PROCEDURE DROP_INDEXES(IN indexs varchar(1000),IN p_database VARCHAR  (8000),IN p_table varchar(8000))
BEGIN
    DECLARE L_SQL VARCHAR(400);
    SET L_SQL= 'DROP INDEX '||trim(indexs)||' ON '||trim(db_name)|| '.'|| trim(tablename); 
    EXECUTE IMMEDIATE L_SQL;        
END ;
```

I need to call this child_procedure(DROP_INDEXES) from parent procedure, but during executing of the parent_procedure, after executing this procedure

```
 CALL DROP_INDEXES(indexs,db_name,tablename);
```

automatically gets exit from the parent_procedure, the next statement is not executing from parent_procedure.

This is the error i'm getting:

```
Executed as Single statement.  Failed [3722 : HY000] SP_DROP_INDEXES:
Only a COMMIT WORK or null statement is legal after a DDL Statement. 
Elapsed time = 00:00:00.326
```

Kindly do help me regarding my issue.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: https://forums.teradata.com/forum/database/ddl-statement-dynamic-sql-in-a-for-cursor-loop-sqlcode-3772

Answer (score 1):

In Teradata each DDL must be committed individually. Your session is running in ANSO mode, thus you need to add `;COMMIT;` to the SQL string.

This should work:

```
SET L_SQL= 'DROP INDEX '||trim(indexs)||' ON '||trim(db_name)|| '.'|| trim(table name) || ';COMMIT;'
```

Comment: thanks for the answer. I tried this query, but still after the execution of this drop statement, the procedure gets EXIT. the next statement is not executing.

Comment: @Vivek Harry: Which error is returned? Is there any CONDITION HANDLER to catch it?

Answer (score 0):

Try a different syntax:

```
REPLACE PROCEDURE DROP_INDEXES(IN indexs varchar(1000), IN p_database    VARCHAR  (8000),IN p_table varchar(8000))
BEGIN
    DECLARE L_SQL VARCHAR(400);
    SET L_SQL= 'DROP INDEX '||trim(indexs)||' ON '||trim(p_database)|| '.'|| trim(p_table); 
    --EXECUTE IMMEDIATE L_SQL;        
    CALL DBC.SysExecSQL( L_SQL );
END ;

REPLACE PROCEDURE PROC_TEST1 (IN db_name varchar(30),IN tablename varchar(30),IN indexs varchar(30))
BEGIN
  CALL DROP_INDEXES(indexs,db_name,tablename); 
  insert into test2 (charcol) select user; 
END;

call proc_test1(DATABASE,'test2','idx_test2');
```

Comment: `EXECUTE IMMEDIATE` does exactly the same as `CALL DBC.SysExecSQL`, it's just a newer, Standard SQL compliant syntax.

Comment: Didn't require explicit commit from me tho.

Comment: Did you run it in ANSI mode or in a Teradata mode session?

Comment: DBC/SQL in Assistant

Comment: @access_granted  I also tried this way, but the moment executed the DDL statement, the upcoming statement is not executing. Simply get exit from the procedure.  And, I don't know, how to run in ANSI mode or Teradata mode Session!!!

Comment: This is odd. It doesn't exit procedure in SQL*Assistant, but when I try the same code in, let's say, JDBC program - it does. So I guess it depends on the client implementation. My client is the 64-bit TD14.